# Where can I find datasets for all confirmed exoplanets, terrestrial exoplanets, and Super-Earth exoplanets?

Tags: resource-recommendations, astronomy, data, exoplanets

"The NASA Exoplanet Archive" (https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/) implies that there are 5,197 confirmed exoplanets. The "5,197 Confirmed Planets 11/02/2022" link leads to a Planetary Systems dataset with 33,719 records with a "Planet Name", perhaps all selected. What are these celestial bodies? That being said, The "All Exoplanets" link at https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/docs/counts_detail.html leads to the Planetary Systems dataset with 5,197 records selected.

"Terrestrial" (https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/what-is-an-exoplanet/planet-types/terrestrial/#otp_how_many_terrestrial_planets_are_out_there?) implies that there are 190 terrestrial exoplanets. The Exoplanet Catalog (https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/discovery/exoplanet-catalog/) may be filtered to list these 190 terrestrial exoplanets. How can I filter the Planet Systems dataset to these 190 terrestrial exoplanets?

"Super-Earth" (https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/what-is-an-exoplanet/planet-types/super-earth/) implies that there are 1,587 Super-Earth exoplanets. The Exoplanet Catalog (https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/discovery/exoplanet-catalog/) may be filtered to list these 1,587 Super-Earth exoplanets. How can I filter the Planet System dataset to these 1,587 Super-Earth exoplanets?

Answer (score 0):

Website [Exoplanet.eu](http://exoplanet.eu/catalog/) contains a list of all exoplanets; you can filter
by status (Confirmed/Candidate), it automatically shows only Confirmed exoplanets. In addition, you can also filter by the method of detection used (Transit method, radial-velocity, etc.). The database contains all known information about those exoplanets and their host stars, which you can retrieve by simply clicking on the planet's name, or you can download the entire dataset. The database is updated daily.